# Native C++ programs in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I'm confused in my understanding of the relationship between Visual Studio and .NET. I want to write a C++ application, but not a "*.NET C++*" application. By this, I mean that my understanding is that everything built in .NET land gets compiled to a CLI-compatible intermediary code (just like "JVM" languages like Java and Groovy compile to the same bytecode).

But I don't want my app compiled to an intermediary bytecode...I want it compiled down to raw binary!

Does Visual Studio do this? Or is .NET forced down my throat the minute I choose VS as my C++ IDE? If so, whats a "raw C++" alternative to VS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MSIL bytecode is "raw binary", just like the machine code found in *native executables*.

Comment: Technically, storage devices don't even store binary. They store electricity. So, technically, nothing is raw binary, just 3- and 5-volt signals.

Comment: Either way, "raw binary" is an ambiguous term, whereas "bytecode", "machine code" and "native executable" are not.  Using unambiguous terms usually helps get better answers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio is an IDE, which is orthogonal to any specific language or compiler.

Visual C++ is a compiler that supports the C, C++, and C++/CLI languages.

In Visual Studio, create a Visual C++ project from one of the 'Win32' (as opposed to 'CLR') project templates and your program won't have any .NET dependency.

Answer (score 3):

there is that /clr compiler switch when compiling a c++ app. Without it, you will get a pure native binary and cannot use any. NET specific features within your code.

By selecting a project template or by setting the corresponding project property, VS will automatically choose if the switch is on or off.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio still supports 100% native C++ applications as will as managed applications.  When creating a new app just choose the "Win32 Console Application" to create a native application.  For existing applications you can change / verify by doing the following

- Right Click on the project and select "Properties"
- Navigate to Configuration Properties -> C/C++
- Make sure that "Common Language Runtime Support" is set to "No Common Language Runtime Support"